# gprof - Top times spent in `std::bad_variant_accesss::~bad_variant_access()`?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, g++, gprof

I'm trying to measure performance of some code I wrote. I compiled it with g++ with `-pg` flag, and when after running it I execute `grpof`, I reliably get `std::bad_variant_access::~bad_variant_access()` among most time-consuming (% time) functions.

No exceptions are actually being thrown by the program and if I try to put a `breakpoint bad_variant_access::~bad_variant_access()` in gdb, it doesn't trigger and the program finishes in one go.

Is there any way to backtrace where all these mysterious calls come from? Could gprof `misfire` and confuse functions?

Comment: What about `std::exception::~exception` or `std::bad_variant_access::bad_variant_access`?

Comment: @user17732522 no, I don't see these in the output. Also, placing breakpoints on them doesn't interrupt execution

Comment: I mean whether the debugger will break on them.

Comment: Edited the comment, it only hits the `std::exception::~exception` breakpoint after the main loop has finished. gdb message: `/usr/src/debug/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_exception.cc: No such file or directory.` Backtrace:
`
#0  std::exception::~exception() (this=0x555555911ec0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_exception.cc:29
#1  0x00007fff93bc8f2c in  () at /usr/lib/libsrt.so.1.5
#2  0x00007fffec053a87 in __cxa_finalize () at /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007fff93b651b8 in  () at /usr/lib/libsrt.so.1.5
#4  0x00007fffffffdad0 in  ()
`

Comment: This also doesn't appear __always__ but pretty often nonetheless, I'm now running a script to test it and so far 27 out of 36 runs had `bad_variant_access` in the gprof output (finished at 77/100)

Comment: OK, so there is an exception at least. What does gdb tell you when running after `catch throw` to break on any exception being thrown?

Comment: It exits normally. No interruptions. After adding back `b exception::~exception()` it exited with SIGPROF once, now it just runs same as without `catch throw` (finishes loop, and stops at a breakpoint at the very end)

Comment: It's very late at where I am, so I'll go to sleep now probably. I'll continue responding in several hours when I wake up.